# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "0" at path "followers"

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose on Node JS server. I created a Follow Route which is working correctly.

```
router.post("/follow/:id/:followerId", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
  const follower = await User.findById(req.params.followerId);

  try {
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, {
      $push: { followers: follower },
    }).then(
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(follower, {
        $push: { followings: user },
      })
    );

    res.send("Done");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

I now created the opposite for unfollow route. But I get this error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "0" at path "followers"
reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

This is my unfollow route:

```
router.post("/unfollow/:id/:followerId", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
  const follower = await User.findById(req.params.followerId);

  try {
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, {
      $pull: { followers: follower },
    }).then(
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(follower, {
        $pull: { followings: user },
      })
    );

    res.send("Done");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

How can I make this work please?

This is my schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  followers: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
  followings: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
});
```

Please help

Comment: Try `$pull: { followers: req.params.followerId}`

Comment: It doesnt give the error again, but it doesnt pull the ids from the array. They still remain. @CuongLeNgoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the schema and how you add a new follower/following.
In the schema, followers and following are arrays of ObjectId

```
 followers: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
  followings: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
```

But, when you add a new follower and following into the array, you use the entire object.

```
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id); // user object
const follower = await User.findById(req.params.followerId);

  try {
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, {
      $push: { followers: follower }, // you use the user object instead of the id
    }).then(
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(follower, {
        $push: { followings: user },
      })
    );
```

I think we should change to the id of the object :

```
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
const follower = await User.findById(req.params.followerId);

  try {
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, {
      $push: { followers: follower._id }, // here we use the id of follower
    }).then(
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(follower, {
        $push: { followings: user._id },
      })
    );
```

and the same when we remove the follower and the following :

```
try {
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, {
      $pull: { followers: follower._id },
    }).then(
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(follower, {
        $pull: { followings: user._id },
      })
    );
```

Note: you may need to check in the database what is in the followers and the followings array, in case they are objects (I think), you should change to id.